# SQL substring charindex

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I have a SQL field with a string like this

```
27/08/2018 to 31/08/2018 - GCH/10561/201312361J/HO
04/09/2018 to 07/09/2018 - GCH/2836/202788279H/WAL
```

This string has a reference code I need to extract. The one bolded above.

The problem is the string before it has not always the same length. See second example above.

How can I extract that code each time?

Ive tried this, but i need to the left of the last "/".....

```
SELECT Right('27/08/2018 to 31/08/2018 - GCH/10561/201312361J/HO', CHARINDEX('/','27/08/2018 to 31/08/2018 - GCH/10561/201312361J/HO')-1)
```

I think I need to use a `substring` and `charindex` but cannot get it working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: which db are you using. oracle, sql server

Comment: Also, can you please identify which version of the db you are using? if you have a `string_split()` function available this could solve the problem for you. (Looks like you are using SQL Server, but need the version.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Is there **always** a `-` before the "second part"?

Comment: Thanks all, will ensure I detail my infrastructure as well as the issue i have next time.. Still learning. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=05862bfed58adcf9907ce9387faaa8b9)

```
declare @text varchar(64)
set @text='27/08/2018 to 31/08/2018 - GCH/10561/201312361J/HO'
select reverse(substring(reverse(right(@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text)-3)),CHARINDEX('/',reverse(right(@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text)-3)))+1,10))
```

OUTPUT:

```
val
201312361J
```

Comment: All of these opption worked perfectly, If i could mark all of them as good I would.

Answer (score 0):

This will locate the wanted string, but it requires quite a deal of reversing to get there. I have used a cross apply but you don't have to.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   column_a VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO test(column_a) VALUES ('27/08/2018 to 31/08/2018 - GCH/10561/201312361J/HO');
INSERT INTO test(column_a) VALUES ('04/09/2018 to 07/09/2018 - GCH/2836/202788279H/WAL');


select
      column_a, ca.x
from test
cross apply (
    select reverse(substring(reverse(column_a),CHARINDEX('/',reverse(column_a))+1,10))
    ) ca (x)
```

Comment: "*If i could mark all of them as good I would*" There is an upvote capability. You might find this interesting:  https://rextester.com/EGO40980

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming MS SQL Server:

```
declare @rev varchar(64)
set @rev=reverse('27/08/2018 to 31/08/2018 - GCH/10561/201312361J/HO')
SELECT 
reverse(SUBSTRING ( @rev,  charindex('/', @rev) + 1, charindex('/', substring(@rev, (charindex('/', @rev) + 1) + 1, Len(@rev)))));
```

Explanation:

- First we reverse the original string using reverse.
- Then we find the substring between the first occurrence of '/' and the next occurrence of '/'
- We reverse the string again to find our original string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Postgres and that the `-` always precedes the second group of information:

```
with test(data) as (
values 
  ('27/08/2018 to 31/08/2018 - GCH/10561/201312361J/HO'), 
  ('04/09/2018 to 07/09/2018 - GCH/2836/202788279H/WAL')
)
select split_part(split_part(data, '-', 2), '/', 3)
from test;
```

returns:

```
split_part
----------
201312361J
202788279H
```